# robot.txt индексировать сайты как разные

Tags: .net, robots.txt

Есть 1000 доменных имен.В зависимости от запроса пользователя, выдается определенный контент.Пример:
 1. site2.com - один контент
 2. site3.com - другой контент
 3. и т.д.

У всех доменов один и тот же IP
как будут роботы индексировать домены? Что необходимо прописать в robot.txt, чтобы их индексировали как разные сайты. спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Индексироваться будут нормально. Это вполне обыденная картина, когда на одном IP висят десятки сайтов. 
В robots ничего дополнительно прописывать не нужно. Необходимым и достаточным условием индексирования всех сайтов будет разный контент на них. Причем этот контент не должен перескакивать с одного домена на другой, т.е. то, что сегодня на site1 завтра НЕ должно оказаться на site58.
P.S. хотя в случае 1000 доменов и описанного механизма генерации подозреваю. что контент будет если не одинаковым, то достаточно близким. А в таком случае поведение должно быть совсем другим.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Контент(наполнение) то везде разный, Одинаковая только верстка везде. Это будет считаться схожим контентом? Уж извините за глупые вопросы)  @Leshll

Comment: Нет. Верстка - это не контент. В интернете сотни сайтов, сделанных на идентичных бесплатных шаблонах (читай - с одинаковой версткой), например, 100500 блогов ЖЖ - и это не мешает им нормально индексироваться и жить своей жизнью.